# Pushing a service to base class using `base` keyword

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, mvp, base-class

Together with dependency injection I'm using `base` key word to push an instance of a service class that was injected to the presenter as follows.

```
class EmployeePresenter : BasePresenter
{
    public EmployeePresenter (IEmployeeView view, IEmployee model, IMessageService messageService) : base (messageService)
    {
        //
    }

    //
}
```

The purpose of this is now I can use services offered by `MessageService` in my `BasePresenter` class.

Is this same as dependency injection? Or else what is the correct term for this? Any technical explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Injection is merely the injection of dependencies into a class. Either through the constructor, properties or methods. The class doesn't' ask for those dependencies (Service Location) but gets them injected. Often the terms is related to [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), since Dependency Injection can be used to adhere to the DIP. But still, you can do Dependency Injection while violating the DIP.

In your case you are injecting your services into your `EmployeePresenter` so you are doing dependency injection in this class. The `BasePresenter` has a constructor with one dependency and the `EmployeePresenter` does dependency injection into the `BasePresenter`'s constructor. So yes, injecting into the base class is a form of dependency injection as well.

Do note though that base classes are often a design smell because they tend to become big [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violations. This starts happening when the base class uses multiple dependencies. Often you'll see that unrelated actions, such as cross-cutting concerns, are all placed into the base class and the base class becomes some sort of [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) or [Utility class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class).

Instead of using base classes for all cross-cutting concerns, there are often more maintainable and flexible ways of applying those concerns. For instance using [decorators](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator) or [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).